# .NET 5.0 Web Applications deployed on Nginx(Ubuntu) not serving static files correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nginx, razor-pages

I have three .NET 5 Web Applications(1 Razor Pages, 1 MVC, 1 Web API) that are deployed on an Ubuntu server(using Nginx) and I want their paths to work like this:

- [www.domain.com/homepage](http://www.domain.com/homepage)
- [www.domain.com/platform](http://www.domain.com/platform)
- [www.domain.com/apis](http://www.domain.com/apis)

..but I have faced several issues when serving the static files (on the MVC app thus far)

##### Platform App configurations

Program.cs

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:8002");
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Startup.cs

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseStaticFiles("/platform");
        app.UsePathBase("/platform");
    }
  
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

The `nginx` configuration

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   domain.azure.com *.domain.azure.com;

    location /homepage/ {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    
    location /platform/ {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /apis/ {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8003;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I have two issues with static files on the MVC app:

##### Issue 1

When the Action is an Index, e.g. `/administration`, the server correctly loads the image like this: `domain.azure.com/platform/assets/images/header.png`

But when attempting to access an Action in a Controller that is not an index (e.g. `/administration/users`) the server tries to load the background images like this `domain.azure.com/platform/administration/assets/images/header.png`.

##### Issue 2

The other issue is with the Identity Razor Pages I have on the MVC app, where the server ignores the `platform` path and tries to serve the page from the domain relative URL, e.g. `domain.azure.com/Identity/Account/Login` instead of `domain.azure.com/platform/Identity/Account/Login`

Can you tell me if I'm missing something on my configurations?

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Could you solve this issue? I'm facing exact same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,  it turns out my setup was correct but I had some issues on the link references. I fixed the static files issue by using relative urls for styles within my views and css files like this: background-image: url(../assets/images/image.jpg) or ~/assets/images/logo.png (depending on your case).. and also for razor pages I used the urls like this: "~/Identity/Account/Login".

Comment: Yes exactly :D
I fixed with same way. Also, It is required to add UsePathBase middleware.
I'll post solution for later usage :)

Answer (score 0):

To make asp.net core work with proxy servers (nginx/apache etc.) it is good to use something called relative urls:
When writing paths anywhere in application, use tilda (~) character in beginning. For example:

`<style src="~/assets/js/app.js"><script>`

After this urls, you need to add `PathBaseMiddleware` by adding

`app.UsePathBase("/myprefix")`

There is [great article by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-6.0) dedicated to this issue.